# How can I organize a shots without duplicating the whole scene?

Tags: animation, workflow

I need a solution which is close to something called "takes" in Cinema4D,
so every "take" contains the overrides to default object properties, e.g. materials, animations, active camera, start and end frame of sequence, etc.

Comment: The closes to takes in Blender is Render Layer, you could also use Scenes. If you need the same objects, you can parent them between scenes or render layers